# Populate the external content below the radiobuttons

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

**Requirement 2:**

Now let me have two radiobuttons "Yes" or "No" below the dropdown menus.

Select first dropdown States as "NY" and second dropdown City as "Niagara" and click "Yes", then external content should load according to the corresponding two dropdown values. If "no", then the corresponding external content should load. Assume any content as an example of your own. Kindly do help me with this. Thank you in advance.

**HTML Code:**

```
<form method="post">States:
    <select name="Select1">
        <option>NJ</option>
        <option>NY</option>
        <option>PA</option>
        <option>TX</option>
    </select>
</form>
<br>
<br>
<form method="post">City List:
    <select name="Select2">
        <option>Trenton</option>
        <option>Albany</option>
        <option>Philly</option>
        <option>Newark</option>
        <option>NYC</option>
        <option>Pittsburgh</option>
        <option>Hackensack</option>
        <option>Niagara</option>
        <option>Harrisburg</option>
    </select>
</form>
<label>Yes</label>
<input type="radio" name="radio" value="Yes" id="yes">
<label>No</label>
<input type="radio" name="radio" value="No" id="no">
```

**JavaScript Code:**

```
$(function () {
    var $States = $('select[name=Select1]');
    var $Cities = $('select[name=Select2]');

    var $citiesList = $Cities.find('option').clone();

    var workerandFruits = {
        NJ: ["Trenton", "Newark", "Hackensack"],
        NY: ["Albany", "NYC", "Niagara"],
        PA: ["Philly", "Pittsburgh", "Harrisburg"]
    }

    $States.change(function () {
        var $selectedWorker = $(this).find('option:selected').text();
        $Cities.html($citiesList.filter(function () {
            return $.inArray($(this).text(), workerandFruits[$selectedWorker]) >= 0;
        }));
    });
});
```

Comment: where is click "yes" and "No"

Comment: @sarath Please have a check now..i have modified the code. Thank you.

Comment: The things you do in .change is very confusing. Make it simple and just leave the code which people can help you with it.